# Authentication not working for Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I've been trying all day long to get nodemailer to work with my Yahoo account.  I'm getting the following authentication error now:

```
 Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.1 Authentication failed
    at SMTPConnection._formatError
```

...

```
 code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 5.7.1 Authentication failed',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

To me it wouldn't make sense to use Oauth because my app has no need to require a login.  I'm just using nodemailer to allow visitors to request a free quote from the company in an input, and then send that text along to the company's yahoo inbox.  Am I thinking about this all wrong?  Here is my controller in case that helps provide any context:

```
require('dotenv').config()
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


module.exports = {
    sendEmail: (req,res) => {
        console.log('-----hit', req.body)
        const { name, email, text } = req.body
        console.log('req.body', name, email, text)

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'yahoo',
            auth: {
                user: process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
                pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASSWORD
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        })


        var mailOptions = {
            from: name + ' ' + process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
            to: process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
            subject: 'New Message From ' + name,
            text: name + ' ' + email + ' ' + text
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `535/7.3.1` is basically an authentication error. When I had this issue, I tried creating a barebones [`smtp`](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer-smtp-transport) transport and mentioning the `name` parameter and set it to the name of the server as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/677#issuecomment-283037667).